# Resetting a Counter at a Certain Point in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to adjust this code so that it resets when the count reaches a certain point, say 20. I'm struggling to determine the best way to go about this in react.js. Below is the code that I'm working with

```
const [position, setPosition] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => setPosition((oldPosition) => oldPosition + 1), 10);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, []);
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Check the `oldPosition` inside `setPosition` callback, if it equals or more than 20, then `clearInterval` **( `setState` callback parameter will always be updated with the latest value )**

```
const [position, setPosition] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => setPosition((oldPosition) => {
      if (oldPosition >= 20) {
         clearInterval(id);
         return oldPosition;
      }
      return oldPosition + 1
    }), 10);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, []);
```